# Aplicação JavaFX não roda em alguns computadores depois de exportada para jar

Tags: java, javafx

Desenvolvi uma aplicação JavaFX, criei um Ant script através do `build.fxbuild` e gerei um jar.

O jar gerado roda Ok no computador no meu serviço e no computador de um outro desenvolvedor, entretanto não roda em dois computadores de não-desenvolvedores, também não roda em duas máquinas virtuais que tenho no meu pc e por incrível que pareça não roda no computador da minha casa, que é de desenvolvedor. Todos os SO que eu tentei são Windows (nenhum era o 7 Home Basic), não acredito que o problema esteja relacionado ao SO.

Quando eu rodo o jar me aparece uma janela:

> JavaFX Launcher Error
>   Exception while running Application

Como mostra a imagem:

[image]

Rodando o jar pelo prompt de comando usando `java -jar meuprojeto.jar` eu recebo o seguinte stack trace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Application launch error
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:122)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._
invokeLater(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._invokeLater(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.invokeLater(Application.java:338)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.defer(QuantumToolkit.java:62
0)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:17
3)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runAndWait(PlatformImpl.java:
212)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.tkExit(PlatformImpl.java:320)

        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
pl.java:421)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:
47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        ... 1 more
```

Eu tenho outras aplicações JavaFX com bem menos dependências que rodam normalmente nesses computadores.

Já verifiquei as variáveis do sistema PATH e parece estar tudo ok.

Eu usei Maven para pegar todas as dependências corretamente (acredito eu), mas infelizmente eu tive que desMavenizar meu projeto em seguida pois eu tive problemas para fazer o deploy através dele, por ser um projeto em JavaFX. Mas eu mantive as dependências que ele me trouxe, e importei da maneira apropriada.

Procurando entender esse erro que não diz nada de coisa nenhuma encontrei uma pergunta que poderia ter me ajudado se tivesse uma resposta decente:

[JavaFX on WindowsXP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18982536/1964435)

A solução medíocre proposta pelo próprio autor não me parece adequada, entretanto me fez pensar que falta alguma dependência no meu jar que foi gerado.

Como eu descubro qual é o problema se a única dica que eu tenho é esse stack trace misterioso? E como solucionar?

Não pretendo utilizar o [JavaFX Maven Plugin](http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/index.html), tive umas experiências ruins com ele e acho que resolverei meu problema pelo Ant bem mais facilmente.

Comment: Só uma dúvida: JavaFX 2.x ou 8?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun 2.2 ponto alguma coisa, se precisar saber o que é o "alguma coisa" eu posso descobrir, mas vai demorar um pouquinho

Comment: Não preciso. A única coisa que deverá ter cuidado ao usar JavaFX 2.2 (i.e Java 7) é que a biblioteca jfxrt.jar **não é incluida por default**. E isso é muitas vezes programadores de JavaFX se esquecem desse detalhe.  

Se não for isso, não terá como te ajudar sem saber o conteúdo das linhas `Main.java:642` e `Main.java:805` embora suspeito que são a chamada da UI.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun com ctz a biblioteca estava incluída. Sobre a linha do Main.java:642, ela não pertence a minha aplicação e sim ao próprio JavaFX, preste atenção no pacote: com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp. No stack trace inteiro não há referência a sequer uma única linha de uma classe desenvolvida por mim, por isso chamei ele de misterioso, ele não me deixou dica quase que nenhuma.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun A propósito, eu já consegui resolver o problema, mas acontece que eu fiz tanta coisa pra tentar resolver que eu não sei exatamente qual delas que foi a solução, eu acho que foi o fato de atualizar o jdk do u25 para o u45, mas não tenho certeza, preciso de um tempo para fazer uns testes e descobrir. E mais do que isso, eu gostaria de saber o que exatamente da minha aplicação faz dar o erro, pois em outra aplicação minha eu não tive problemas. Também tenho que testar a solução sugerida pela resposta abaixo. Só sei que são várias as possibilidades, rsrs..

Answer (score 1):

Tente exportar normalmente como 'runnable jar file' marcando a seguinte opção:

[image]

é provável que o empacotamento das dependencias esteja implicando na execução, deixando na responsabilidade do SO de encontrar algumas libs.

Comment: Você quer dizer que pelas dependências estarem no formato jar ao invés de classes em pastas pode implicar em algum problema para encontrar as dependencias?

Comment: Sim, para jar's executáveis é interessante ter dentro do jar as dependencias organizadas em pastas. Normalmente, um arquivo JAR dentro de um arquivo JAR não pode ser carregado pelo JVM. Desta forma o Eclipse adiciona classes especiais no JAR executável para tornar isso possível.

Comment: Como eu andei fazendo algumas mudanças radicais no meu projeto eu terei que recriar as condições do erro acima e testar, vou te pedir um pouco de paciência enquanto não faço isso. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Se você usou Javafx 8, precisa atualizar a Java Virtual Machine, no caso, deveria ser o JRE 8.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html