# erro ao executar JavaFX no Windows 7

Tags: java, javafx

Recentemente fiz um aplicativo simples no MacOSX (lion) usando JavaFX.

Porém a jogar algumas libs (jar) e implementar mais alguns trechos de código, o aplicativo parou de funcionar no Windows 7.

Ao executar o `aplicativo.jar` é mostrado o erro:

> Exception while running Application

Imagem do erro:

[image: imagem de ERRO]

Alguém já passou por isso ou sabe como posso ver se tá lançando alguma `exception`?

O Estranho é que o aplicativo abria normalmente no Windows.

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu JDK?

Comment: Para ver se tá lançando exception execute ele pelo cmd com o comando: `java -jar aplicativo.jar`

Comment: Não se anime tanto, quando você mais precisar ela vai te deixar na mão, rs.. Mas me diz o JDK que eu estou curioso. Veja isso: [Aplicação JavaFX não roda em alguns computadores depois de exportada para jar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17331/3117)

Comment: @Math executando o aplicativo dessa maneira, ele abriu. Porque clicando em cima do jar ele não abre e aparece a janela de erro?? Sabe de dizer? Grande abraço e obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Esse é um grande mistério, eu desconfio que seja um bug da versão 1.7.0, que surgiu antes ou no u25, e foi consertado até o u45. Essas são as minhas desconfianças, mas esse bug é tão misterioso que eu ainda não consegui descobrir.

Comment: Tente rodar em uma máquina Windows que não possui o JDK instalado e tão somente a JRE, e veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: Estou usando a versão JDK 1.7.

Muito obrigado mesmo Math. A sua ajuda foi excelente!